# Transpose Numpy Array (Vector)

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([0,1,2])
b = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])

...

c = np.dot(a,b)
```

I want to transpose b so I can calculate the dot product of a and b.

Comment: Dot product for 1d arrays of different size is not defined.  If the 2 arrays have same size, `dot` produces the inner product.  What `c` do you want?  I suspect you want the `np.outer` product, not inner or matrix product.

Comment: You can dot the both 1d arrays if you can transpose b. a-colums = b-rows = 1. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can't transpose a 1d array.  You can, of course, add dimension, making a (1,n) or (n,1).  But I still don't know what `c` is supposed to be.

Comment: What `c` are you expecting?

Comment: Maybe you mean `np.array([ a * bb for bb in b ])`?

Comment: I want this (3,) array to become (3,1) and the (5,) array to become (1,5). Maybe the question is stupid np arrays confuse me a little.

Comment: So `c = np.array([ [bb] for bb in b])` then `a * c`?

Comment: Reshaping the arrays to those dimensions is a basic `numpy` operation.  No need to think in terms of transposition.

Comment: I want c to be: [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 6  8 10 12 14]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use numpy's broadcasting for this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,1,2])
b = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])


In [3]: a[:,None]*b
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  8, 10, 12, 14]])
```

This has nothing to do with a dot product, though. But in the comments you said, that you want this result.

You could also use the numpy function `outer`:

```
In [4]: np.outer(a, b)
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  8, 10, 12, 14]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for this what you want is the outer product of the two arrays. The function you want to use for this is [`np.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html), :

```
a = np.array([0,1,2])
b = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])

np.outer(a,b)

array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  8, 10, 12, 14]])
```

Comment: What is the difference between `np.outer` and `np.multiply.outer`?

Comment: Was just wondering, because I just put the function in my answer like two minutes before you posted your answer and I thought, yours did something different :D But now I learned about `np.add.outer` which is nice :D

Comment: Ahh no the same, just that `np.ufunc.outer` can be used for multiple operations. Good answer btw +1

Answer (score 0):

So with NumPy you could reshape swapping axes:

```
a = np.swapaxes([a], 1, 0)
# [[0]
#  [1]
#  [2]]
```

Then

```
print(a * b)

# [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
#  [ 3  4  5  6  7]
#  [ 6  8 10 12 14]]
```

Swapping `b` require to transpose the product, se here below.

---

Or usual NumPy reshape:

```
a = np.array([0,1,2])
b = np.array([3,4,5,6,7]).reshape(5,1)

print((a * b).T)

# [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
#  [ 3  4  5  6  7]
#  [ 6  8 10 12 14]]
```

Reshape is like `b = np.array([ [bb] for bb in [3,4,5,6,7] ])` then `b` becomes:

```
# [[3]
#  [4]
#  [5]
#  [6]
#  [7]]
```

---

While reshaping `a` no need to transpose:

```
a = np.array([0,1,2]).reshape(3,1)
b = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])

print(a * b)

# [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
#  [ 3  4  5  6  7]
#  [ 6  8 10 12 14]]
```

---

Just out of curiosity, **good old list comprehension**:

```
a = [0,1,2]
b = [3,4,5,6,7]
print( [ [aa * bb for bb in b] for aa in a ] )

#=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 8, 10, 12, 14]]
```

Comment: OPs expected output is yours, but transposed, so you might want to add a `.T`  there

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided the `outer` and broadcasted solutions.  Here's the `dot` one(s):

```
np.dot(a.reshape(3,1), b.reshape(1,5))    
a[:,None].dot(b[None,:])
a[None].T.dot( b[None])
```

Conceptually I think it's a bit of an overkill, but due to implementation details, it actually is fastest
.

Comment: This is actually faster than my answer? Do you have some times? Can you explain? I'm really interested tbh